# SocketException: Permission Denied?

Tags: android, url, inputstream, permission-denied, socketexception

My LogCat reads:

```
08-19 09:29:01.964: WARN/System.err(311): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
08-19 09:29:02.204: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
08-19 09:29:02.214: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
08-19 09:29:02.214: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
08-19 09:29:02.224: WARN/System.err(311):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
08-19 09:29:02.224: WARN/System.err(311):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1020)
08-19 09:29:02.224: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
08-19 09:29:02.224: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
08-19 09:29:02.224: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
08-19 09:29:02.224: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
08-19 09:29:02.234: WARN/System.err(311):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1152)
08-19 09:29:02.234: WARN/System.err(311):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:653)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at around.lowell.Main.onCreate(Main.java:57)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 09:29:02.244: WARN/System.err(311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-19 09:29:02.254: WARN/System.err(311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 09:29:02.254: WARN/System.err(311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-19 09:29:02.254: WARN/System.err(311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-19 09:29:02.264: WARN/System.err(311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-19 09:29:02.264: WARN/System.err(311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code that I have recently implemented that it is generating this error for in my Android app is:

```
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = this.openFileOutput("employeeInformation.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
            try {
                InputStream is = new URL("http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/code/employees.xml").openStream();
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                fOut.write(buffer);
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: @William that question was asked asked Jun 30 '12  this one asked Aug 19 '11 almost a year earlyer...

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Add Internet permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Well that was a lot simpler than expected.. thank you very much!

Comment: I had to restart my emulator and then re-deploy again before the change would take effect.

Comment: Physical device attached via USB: I had to uninstall the app and re-run (no restart was required)

Answer (score 7):

You need to go to your Manifest file in your android application project then above `application` section next to other permissions add: `android.permission.INTERNET`

Your manifest should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
....
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
....
```

keep in mind value (`android.permission.INTERNET`) is case sensitive.

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: this is right, the value (android.permission.INTERNET) is case sensitive. We must add space between " and / also.